# How to write an ordered collection for Comparable classes and classes with Comparators all in one

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I am interested in implementing a special variant of a Priority Queue in Java, and I want this priority queue to work with generic types. In Java's collection objects that store objects with some sort of ordering (e.g. PriorityQueue, TreeSet, etc.), it is possible to use classes that implement Comparable as well as classes that don't necessarily implement Comparable, given that a Comparator for the class is passed in to the constructor.

How can I implement this functionality into my Priority Queue class? Do I have to rewrite all of my methods depending on whether the class implements Comparable vs if I was given a Comparator? Or is there a way I can get a Comparator from a class that implements Comparable, so I only have to deal with the Comparator case?

Comment: Have you looked at the source for `PriorityQueue`, etc., to see how they do it? The source of the JDK classes is in `src.jar` in your JDK directory. (Hint: No, there's no need to have two versions of all your methods. depending on whether you have a comparator...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a `PriorityQueue` in Java already has [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) that [take a `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-int-java.util.Comparator-).  If you are attempting to subclass `PriorityQueue`, then it's unnecessary to determine if you should use a `Comparator` vs. rely on `Comparable`.  Supply constructors that call the matching superclass constructors.

However, if you are creating your own priority queue, then you can make the decision once when you are constructing your priority queue.

If a `Comparator` is supplied, then store it for later use.  If a `Comparator` is not supplied, then (assuming Java 8+) use an instance of [`Comparator.naturalOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--).

Without Java 8, implement `Comparator.naturalOrder` by using the [Adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).  The type parameter for this adapter class `T` is constrained to be `Comparable`, so a `ClassCastException` may result if the objects added aren't `Comparable` and a `Comparator` wasn't supplied.  That's okay; you can't constrain your priority queue's type parameter to be `Comparable` if you want to allow a `Comparator` to be passed in for comparing, because `Comparator` doesn't restrict its type parameter this way.

The `compare` method simply delegates to `Comparable`'s `compareTo` method.

```
class ComparableToComparator<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparator<T> {
    @Override
    public int compare(T a, T b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

(This is pretty much what `Comparator.naturalOrder` does.)

Whether a `Comparator` is passed in or not, you have a `Comparator` to use.  It's either the one that was passed in, or an instance of the above class that attempts to treat the objects as `Comparable`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--)?

Comment: Ok cool! Using a design like this, if a user tries supplying a class that doesn't implement Comparable, and they don't supply a Comparator, how can I ensure that I get an appropriate error during compile time?

Comment: @user129137 You can't, same as you don't if you use the built-in `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: @Andreas Oh - I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for all of your help Andreas!

Comment: @user129137 I take that back, you can. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49016098/5221149).

Answer (score 0):

The built-in [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) has constructors for creating a queue using [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) objects, and for creating a queue using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

- [`PriorityQueue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue--) - orders its elements according to their **natural ordering**.
- [`PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) - ordered according to the specified comparator.

The easiest way to implement your own class with similar semantics, is to always use a `Comparator`, and just use the natural comparator when none is provided:

```
public class MyOrderedCollection<E> {

    private final Comparator<? super E> comparator;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public MyOrderedCollection() {
        this((Comparator<? super E>) Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }

    public MyOrderedCollection(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }
}
```

---

If you want to ensure you get compilation error if creating the collection on an object that is not `Comparable` without supplying a `Comparator`, you can guard against that by using factory methods:

```
public class MyOrderedCollection<E> {

    private final Comparator<? super E> comparator;

    public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> MyOrderedCollection<E> of() {
        return new MyOrderedCollection<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }

    public static <E> MyOrderedCollection<E> of(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        return new MyOrderedCollection<>(comparator);
    }

    private MyOrderedCollection(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }
}
```

Now you don't even have to suppress compilation warnings.

With that, it works like this:

```
MyOrderedCollection<String> x = MyOrderedCollection.of();

MyOrderedCollection<Object> y = MyOrderedCollection.of(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));

MyOrderedCollection<Object> z = MyOrderedCollection.of(); // compilation error
```